# Cast a CollectionBase subclass to a generic List without specifying the type explicitly

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

I have subclasses of `CollectionBase` like this:

```cs
public abstract class BaseList : CollectionBase
{
    public abstract Type ListType { get; }
}

public class MyClassList : BaseList
{
    public override Type ListType
    {
        get { return typeof(MyClass); }
    }
}
```

So I know the types at compile-time. I want to add a method `ToGenericList()` to
my `BaseList` class that will convert any `BaseList` to a generic `List` of type
`ListType`.

This does not work:

```cs
public List<T> ToGeneric<T>()
{
    return List.Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

because "the type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage." Clearly, I could
just do this:

```cs
someList.Cast<MyClass>().ToList();
```

or this:

```cs
someList.ToGeneric<MyClass>();
```

But this gets *extremely* cumbersome when I'm working with objects that have
lists of lists of lists and I want to use a bunch of LINQ methods on them all and the class names are 30+ characters long.

Is there any solution that does not involve the caller specifying the type or
casting at all?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't make a generic `BaseList<T>` in the first place ?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Yes. I did not design this system, the person who did no longer works for this company, and coworkers imitate the previous design when writing new code for consistency. This old, convoluted system now has thousands of lines using these custom non-generic lists. Yet, my coworkers and I still use LINQ often by `.Cast<>()`ing to generics. But, like I said, it gets cumbersome.

Comment: You could define a separate `ToList()` on each subclass, specifying the correct type there: `public List<MyClass> ToGeneric()`, for example.. I don't think there's a way to make this work with a BaseClass method.

Comment: @Blorgbeard thanks, see my comment on DStanley's answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's not a way to get the compiler to infer by return type.  One option would be to add a method to each collection type to return a generic collection:

```
public class MyClassList : BaseList
{
    public override Type ListType
    {
        get { return typeof(MyClass); }
    }
    public List<MyClass> ToGeneric()
    {
        return this.Cast<MyClass>.ToList();
    }
}
```

Note that there's not a way to put this on the base class since the only thing that changes is the return type (you can't overload a method by changing the return type only).

If you can't / don't want to change the base types you *could* make them extension methods, but you'll still have to have a method for each type.

Comment: Yes, I've thought of that, but we have over 400 subclasses deriving from `BaseList`, and I thought it impractical. Oh well, thank you.

Comment: Are you certain that there's no possible way to do this from the base class? If so, I'll unfortunately have to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific naming convention for your lists, you could try the big bang approach.

First, declare a second base class, introducing an intermediary hierarchy level:

```
public abstract class BaseList<T> : BaseList, IList<T>
{
    public override Type ListType { get { return typeof(T); } }

    // Delegate IList<T> implementation to the base class

    public new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return base.Cast<T>().GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return base.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        base.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return base.Remove(item);
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return base.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        base.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public new T this[int index]
    {
        get { return (T)base[index]; }
        set { base[index] = value; }
    }
}
```

Then, well... perform a regex replacement over your code. You can use the VS *Replace in Files* tool for this.

Find:

```
\bclass\s+(\w+)List\s*:\s*BaseList\b
```

Replace with:

```
class $1List : BaseList<$1>
```

Whether this is doable depends on your codebase, but it may be a start.

Once done, you can get rid of the now superfluous `ListType` overrides.